# TF30172 error while using Visual Studio 2008 Bid

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tfs, team-explorer

I have the following error while trying to connect / create team project in visual studio 2008 SP1 BIDS to team foundation 2013.  How do I upgrade the Team explorer in VS 2008 with new version to connect to TFS 2013?

[image: TF30172 error]

thanks

Nick

Comment: Checkout this post: http://blog.jessehouwing.nl/2013/10/connecting-to-tfs-from-any-version-of.html?spref=tw&m=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant. Visual Studio 2008 connecting to TFS is no longer supported. You can however install the MSSCCI provider to allow down level source only connection.

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/06c8e056-7f77-4a5c-9b8b-49318c143df8

In order to be able to create a new Team Project against TFS 2013 you need to install the 2013 version of Team Explorer. It resides within the VS 2013 shell so if you can I would recommend installing VS2013.

Team Explorer 2013: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40776